Syntax to pull filename.ext*, but not filename.ext*.*
I mean I can't figure this one out so far.
file1.ext1
file7.ext2
fileQ.ext3
# should be accepted
file1.ext1.bak
# should not be accepted

@tim roberts - almost there, except file1.ext11 or file1.extAB won't work - but let me try a few things, t/u!

For that example, you could use *.ext?.

If you have multiple digits after "ext" you could try *.ext+([0-9])

ksh,bash *.ext+([^.]) zsh *.ext*~*.ext*.*

grep -v means "grep not".

If you need to match both letters and numbers after .ext, you can try:
ls -lh file*.ext+([0-9a-zA-Z])

In the square brackets you can define which characters/ranges of characters should be accepted (or which explicitly shouldn't)
If you want to accept everything but another dot(s), you can use @yvs2014's suggestion, where ^ is used for negation:
ls -lh file*.ext+([^.])


Worked in KSH93u; bash (5.2.15(1)-release) responded with "-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('" for all syntax options - including Jared's and yvs2014's

@access_granted enable that globbing in bash with shopt -s extglob and try again

yvs2014, you are correct. You'd think a simple ls would require less maintenance, but nooo
